# how does Breeze saves empty strings

Tags: entity-framework-5, breeze

I am retrieving an entity from the database with some proprieties.

One of the proprieties is not allowed to be not null string in the database. Even though is not null it can be an empty string `""`.

In the EF mappings the propriety is validated like:

```
this.Property(t => t.ColumnName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);
```

The problem is that when I am trying to save the changes with Breeze it returns an error for the elements that have the propriety `ColumnName` equal to an empty string.(saying `"ColumnName is required"`).

Is this accepted behaviour? Shouldn't the error be thrown only if the the `ColumnName` would be `null` or `undefined`?

The error Breezejs throws:

```
valError: Error
    entityErrors: Array[5]
        0: Object
            entity: Object
                ColumnName: function dependentObservable() {
                    __ko_proto__: function (evaluatorFunctionOrOptions, evaluatorFunctionTarget, options) {
                    _latestValue: ""
                    _subscriptions: Object
                    ...
                ...
                entityAspect: ctor
                __proto__: Object
            errorMessage: "'ColumnName' is required"
            errorName: "required"
            isServerError: false
            propertyName: "ColumnName"
            __proto__: Object
```

Comment: and the metadata `{\"name\":\"ColumnName\",\"type\":\"Edm.String\",\"fixedLength\":\"false\",\"maxLength\":\"50\",\"unicode\":\"true\",\"nullable\":\"false\"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with how Breeze saves data.

What you are encountering is Breeze's validation logic.  Breeze defaults to treating empty strings as nulls for the purposes of validating "required" fields.  You can change this by replacing Breeze's required validator to simply treat required as meaning "not null".

```
Validator.required = function (context) {
    var valFn = function (v, ctx) {
        return v != null;
    }
    return new Validator("required", valFn, context);
};
// register the new validator so that metadata can find it. 
Validator.registerFactory(Validator.required, "required");
```

Comment: Where can I replace the Validator?

Comment: Best time would be at start up immediately after Breeze is loaded; then just use breeze.Validator.required = ...

Comment: I am modifying the required Validator right after the Metadata is retrieved. Following in the debugger I could see that still the old version of the validator was used.  Browsing through the source I found this `if (ctx && ctx.allowEmptyStrings) return true;` and I was thinking maybe it would be more appropriate to set the value of `ctx.allowEmptyStrings` to true...

Comment: The ctx.allowEmptyStrings code has a small bug that will be fixed in the next release, so don't try using it yet (which is why we haven't doc'd it yet).  But even with that fixed the problem is that this switch will only allow you to create a new validator by passing in a context object that contains a custom context containing { allowEmptyStrings: true }.  You would still need to replace the stock "required" validator "factory".i.e. Validator.required. I also updated the answer above with some additional information.

Comment: I had to update the `required` validator before the Metadata is retrieved and it worked.