# how to make the breezejs required validator allow empty strings

Tags: validation, breeze

What is the preferred way in breezejs to allow empty strings in required properties?

I found [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658297/how-does-breeze-saves-empty-strings) which recommends replacing the required validator like this:

```
Validator.required = function (context) {
    var valFn = function (v, ctx) {
        return v != null;
    }
    return new Validator("required", valFn, context);
};
// register the new validator so that metadata can find it. 
Validator.registerFactory(Validator.required, "required");
```

There's also mention of a `allowEmptyStrings` flag somewhere.

What is the preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a 'required' validator that allows empty string like this:

```
var v0 = Validator.required({ allowEmptyStrings: true });
```

Comment: Is the original technique of replacing the required validator factory still the preferred way for allowing empty string globally?

Comment: @JayTraband: It'd be really nice to have an update on this.

Comment: @JeremyDanyow how did you implement this globally ?