# how to use knockout validation

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze, knockout-validation

I am following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996449/knockout-validation) to create validations.

But i dont understand how can i use this **extend** method in my code.

I load data into my observable with records coming from calling breeze query.

I load data in below manner

```
dataObsArray= ko.observableArray()

datacontext.getData(id,dataObsArray)
                   .then(function () {

          // some logic


 })
        .fail("Data not found");
```

Then i bind this obs array to my view as below

```
<tbody data-bind="with: dataObsArraay">
            <tr>
                <td>name</td>
                <td> <input data-bind="  value: Name" ></td>
                <td> <input data-bind="  value: Age" ></td>

            </tr>
</tbody>
```

So i dont understand how can i use **extend** method because i am just using binding my view with properties in my observable array.

Please guide me.

Comment: well in you view model do you have a function with entities i.e name , age etc . if there you need to use `.extend({//logic here})` .

Comment: i can help you posting some answer with knockout way but i ain't have no clue about breeze

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [breeze validation](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/validation) instead of putting the validation logic in the UI code via a knockout extender.  Using breeze validation will ensure the rules are always evaluated and will save you from creating an extra model over your entity for the purposes of validation.

here's an example using one of breeze's built in validators:  the stringLength validator.

```
var entityType = entityManager.metadataStore.getEntityType('????'),
    nameProperty = entityType.getProperty('Name'),
    nameLengthValidator = breeze.Validator.stringLength({ maxLength: 10, minLength: 2 });
nameProperty.validators.push(nameLengthValidator);
```

here's an example of a custom required validator for strings that doesn't allow whitespace-only values:

```
// make a reusable validator
var myRequiredValidator = breeze.Validator.makeRegExpValidator(
    "myRequiredValidator",  
    /\S/,  
    "The %displayName% '%value%' cannot be blank or entirely whitespace");

// register it with the breeze Validator class.
breeze.Validator.register(myRequiredValidator);

// add the validator to the Name property...
var entityType = entityManager.metadataStore.getEntityType('????'),
    nameProperty = entityType.getProperty('Name');
nameProperty.validators.push(nameLengthValidator);
```

here's the [documentation](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/Validator.html#method_makeRegExpValidator) for making regex validators.

You can also write custom validators- check the [breeze docs](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/validation) for more info on that- look for the *Write a custom validator* section.

Comment: What kind of validation i use if i use space in my inputbox? I put [Required] attribute on my entity but when i try to save i get entityAspect.hasValidationErrors as false.. I dont want user to only blank spaces

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23478929/how-to-make-the-breezejs-required-validator-allow-empty-strings

Comment: i dont want to allow just spaces in my string.. i also tried this on my entities [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]

Comment: i am trying to put it on my entity directly. like this 
[Required]
        [Column(TitleCol, TypeName = "varchar")]
        [MaxLength(1000)]
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }

Comment: In other words, you want breeze to respect the .NET data annotations related to validation.  It does in some cases, in others you need to supplement the breeze metadata and add your own custom validations.  Check out this question for more info on that:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/26570638/725866

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to create a model for your data, e.g.:

```
function person(name, age) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name).extend({ minLength: 2, maxLength: 10 });
    this.age = ko.observable(age).extend({ min: 18, max: 99 });
}

var data = [],
    people = ko.observableArray();

datacontext.getData(id, data)
    .then(function (data) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            people.push(new person(data.Name, data.Age));
        }
    })
    .fail("Data not found");


<tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
    <tr>
        <td>name</td>
        <td> <input data-bind="  value: name" ></td>
        <td> <input data-bind="  value: age" ></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```